# Sending an image from android client to a local server on windows made with NetBeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, outputstream

I'm trying to send an image from a client running on android to a **local** server that's running on Windows, made with NetBeans.

I'm sending text successfully, but i need to send an image.

I tried encoding the image in android using `base64` like that :

```
private BufferedWriter OutPut;
.
.
OutPut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ConnectionSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
//Converting the image to a string where `AppBitmapIcon` is a Bitmap image and i'm getting the bytes array from the function `getBitmapBytes`
String ImgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBitmapBytes(AppBitmapIcon), Base64.NO_WRAP);
OutPut.write(ImgString);

public static byte[] getBitmapBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

But i couldn't finde a way in NetBeans to decode this string converting it to an image and setting it as a icon for a JLabel becasue NetBeans don't has a imageView to handle images.

Anyone can help me to display the image in NetBeans or maybe try another method than encoding it and decoding it?

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why you would have a problem displaying an image with netbeans.   What is the reason you want to base64 encode the image before sending?  For me you can send the image as is. No encoding.

Comment: @greenapps Can you please help me with sending the image as is?

Comment: Just send that byte array. But dont use an output stream writer then. Use a DataOutputStream. Or just the output stream.

Comment: Yes. But use a different output stream. Writers are for text. And your bytes contain an image.

Comment: @greenapps Okay, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can decode base64 string to BufferedImage, then BufferedImage to ImageIcon, then set ImageIcon as icon of JLabel.** Try the following code:-

```
String base64 = "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";
    byte[] btDataFile = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(btDataFile));
        jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test_Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I am using a sample base64 string along with a sample jframe which contains a jlabel. *jLabel1 is the variable name* of the jLabel which is iconized by the base64 string. And a jlabel with imageicon is the way to display images in J2SE applications (in my knowledge). you can check this github repository for more details : [Base64-String_Manipulation](https://github.com/Baneeishaque/Base64-String_Manipulation). Also i am using [Apache commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library for decoding purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the import for the Base64 class? because It can not find `decodeBase64` method inside the `Base64` class, there is no such method.

Comment: There is this import : `import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;` this is the only worked for me. and the method called `decode()`, it takes the encoded text and return the result as byte[].

Comment: Download Apache commons-codec library from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/ , put it in your classpath. then use this import statement `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`